# Substitute literals in MySQL Python prepared statement

Tags: prepared-statement, mysql-python

I'm new to MySQL Python connector and I'm trying to find out if in prepared statement I can substitute non-parameters? Here's example of query that I need to execute repeatedly while decrementing the counter:

```
UPDATE
        material_forecast_series sfs
    JOIN material_forecast sf ON sfs.F_ID = sf.F_ID
    JOIN material_demand sd ON sd.date_ID = sf.date_ID
        AND sd.D_ID = sfs.D_ID
    JOIN material_demand_series ds ON sfs.D_ID = ds.D_ID
    JOIN OMG_membership om ON ds.item_ID = om.item_ID
    JOIN material_FE sfe ON sfe.F_ID = sf.F_ID
SET sfe.v2 = IF(sf.v2 = 0, NULL, (sd.quantity - sf.v2) / sf.v2)
    WHERE
        sfs.forecast_ID = 15
            AND ds.demand_ID = 9
            AND ds.O_ID = 2
            AND om.OG_ID = 318
            AND sd.date_ID = 275
            AND sfe.date_ID = 274
```

In the snippet above last parameter `sfe.date_ID` will be decremented in the loop. No problem there, I will simply do `sfe.date_ID=%s`. However in this line: `SET sfe.v2 = IF(sf.v2 = 0, NULL, (sd.quantity - sf.v2) / sf.v2)` literal `v2` needs to be changed to `v3, v4, v5...` each loop iteration. No problem if I'm to use Python parameter substitution and regular cursor but I want to use prepared statement for performance reason.
Any other tricks to improve performance are greatly appreciated as well

Comment: how many items are there in v3, v4, v5...? do you need to increment them together with sfe.date_ID? Is it true that if you decrement sfe.date_ID 100 times you'll end up updating sfe.v100?

Comment: In most common scenario it's v13 but I don't anticipate it to ever reach v100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a DynamicSQL , doing something like this inside your loop with the variable up_counter getting incremented in the end

```
    set @up_counter = 1
    set @dynamic_sql_1 = 'UPDATE '
    ' material_forecast_series sfs '
    ' JOIN material_forecast sf ON sfs.F_ID = sf.F_ID '
    ' JOIN material_demand sd ON sd.date_ID = sf.date_ID '
    ' AND sd.D_ID = sfs.D_ID '
    ' JOIN material_demand_series ds ON sfs.D_ID = ds.D_ID '
    ' JOIN OMG_membership om ON ds.item_ID = om.item_ID '
    ' JOIN material_FE sfe ON sfe.F_ID = sf.F_ID '
    'SET sfe.v'

    set @dynamic_sql_2 = CONCAT(@up_counter,' = IF(sf.v',',@up_counter,' = 0, NULL, (sd.quantity - sf.v',@up_counter,') / sf.v',@up_counter,')')

    Set @dynamic_sql_2 = '  WHERE '
    'sfs.forecast_ID = 15 '
    ' AND ds.demand_ID = 9 '
    ' AND ds.O_ID = 2 '
    ' AND om.OG_ID = 318 '
    ' AND sd.date_ID = 275 '
    ' AND sfe.date_ID = %s '

    Set @final_sql = CONCAT(@dynamic_sql_1,@dynamic_sql_2,@dynamic_sql_2)

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @final_sql; 
    EXECUTE stmt1 ; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

    set @up_counter = @up_counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not possible.  To quote [the documentation of `PREPARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html) (emphasis on “data values” is mine):

> Statement names are not case sensitive. ***`preparable_stmt`*** is either a string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the SQL statement. The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements. Within the statement, `?` characters can be used as parameter markers to indicate where **data values** are to be bound to the query later when you execute it. The `?` characters should not be enclosed within quotation marks, even if you intend to bind them to string values. Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

Since the field names such as `v2` and `v3` are syntactically not data values but identifiers, you can't use prepared statements to substitute them for placeholders.

Comment: However, if you are fine with as many prepared statements as there are the “v” variables, you can always do so (don't forget checking [`max_prepared_stmt_count`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count) and increasing them if necessary, though).  But I'm pretty sure you already knew this was a possibility.  :)